# "What if we change X" vs "What if we changed X"

Tags: idioms

When you want to say that something can be changed, the following expressions can be used:

- What if we changed X
- What if we change X

I'm wondering if both are correct and when one is preferred over the other.

Comment: Hi, Bernard, just dropping in as part of the community review. Short Answer: Both your phrasings are fine, but this is because the context is so broad. I haven't downvoted your question or anything, but if the question does have context, it might be a good idea to add it to keep this question from being closed :O. Meanwhile, welcome to the English Language Learners Stack Exchange!

Comment: "What if we changed X" emphasizes the result, while "What if we change X" emphasizes the action of changing something. But it is a minor difference. Adding some example sentences would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> What if we changed X

This can somewhat imply what we are working on (applying the change to) is completed.  This sentence might also be used if some time has passed and it is too late to change X.

> What if we change X

This more implies whatever we are applying the change to is not yet completed.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to express the hypothetical in several ways:

> What if we change...
>
> What if we were to change...
>
> What if we changed...
>
> What if we should change...

**What if** does most of the work, so to speak, to indicate the nature of the utterance, that it is a hypothetical.  The verb form can either rely 100% upon "what if" (simple present indicative "we change") or it can  help "what if" do some of the communication,  in which case the verb corroborates the meaning and "shoulders some of the burden" by changing to a non-present-indicative form.